# Transparent PNG texture casting shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, transparency

I'm attempting to overlay a transparent PNG texture over a plane to create a glowing cutout effect. However, the transparent regions of the cutout aren't actually transparent and are casting a shadow on the floor below. Below are the top, side and node setup of the plane with the texture.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to unplug the Color input of **Transparent BSDF**. Set it's color to pure white.

Comment: @PaulGonet Thanks. That worked. Could you put it in the answer while explaining what the color input of the transparent shader actually do? I would appreciate it if you explain when it should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the transparent bsdf to one color (solid white: 1, 1, 1...alpha is disregarded). For this shader to be truly "transparent," the color must be so.

[image]

Transparency color levels from left to right: 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, and 1 (yes, there is an invisible monkey on the end).

Here is the demo blend:

[image]

And here is a link to the transparent shader in the manual:

https://www.blender.org/manual//render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/transparent.html

---

The color can also be used to tint (it doesn't have to be the same for R, G, and B channels):

[image]

From left to right, the RGB color is as follows: (0.5, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0.75, 0), (0.75, 1, 0.75), (1, 1, 0).

Comment: Does the transparent shader take in RGB or RGBA? If its RGBA like you said, then whats the alpha channel doing if the RGB determines transparency? I am currently assuming that the transparency is the saturation of the color.

Comment: Transparency is based on the *value* of the color (black-->white). The alpha doesn't do anything: I've updated my answer.

Comment: As I understand Color is 3 values. How is transparency determined? (Unless its the grayscale value) Also, I assume the RGB tints the transparent material?

Comment: Yes, RGB tints the transparency...the amount of transparency is determined by the grayscale value. I will add a color demo to my answer.

Comment: Great clarification. Thanks for the explanation.